# WINBUGS : adding time and product fixed effects in a hierarchical data

Tags: panel, hierarchical-data, winbugs

I am working on a Hierarchical panel data using WinBugs. Assuming a data on school performance - logs with independent variable logp & rank. All schools are divided into three categories (cat) and I need beta coefficient for each category (thus HLM). I am wanting to account for time-specific and school specific effects in the model. One way can be to have dummy variables in the list of variables under mu[i] but that would get messy because my number of schools run upto 60. I am sure there must be a better way to handle that.

```
My data looks like the following:
school time logs logp  cat rank
1       1    4.2   8.9    1     1
1       2    4.2   8.1    1     2
1       3    3.5   9.2    1     1
2       1    4.1   7.5    1     2
2       2    4.5   6.5    1     2
3       1    5.1   6.6    2     4
3       2    6.2   6.8    3     7


#logs = log(score)
#logp = log(average hours of inputs)
#rank - rank of school
#cat = section red, section blue, section white in school (hierarchies)
```

My WinBUGS code is given below.

```
model {
# N observations

for (i in 1:n){

logs[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
mu[i] <- bcons +bprice*(logp[i])
         + brank[cat[i]]*(rank[i])

}
}
}
# C categories
for (c in 1:C) {
brank[c] ~ dnorm(beta, taub)}

 # priors 
bcons ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-6)
bprice ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-6)
bad ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-6)
beta ~ dnorm(0,1.0E-6)
tau ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001)
taub ~dgamma(0.001,0.001)

}
```

As you can see in the data sample above, I have multiple observations for school over time. How can I modify the code to account for time and school specific fixed effects. I have used STATA in the past and we get fe,be,i.time options to take care of fixed effects in a panel data. But here I am lost.